# How to remove the small border between the cells of a WPF Grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've an issue with a complex view where I got some "border". They are not really border, they are more some kind transparent border that show the background.

I managed to reproduce the issue with a very simple example.

This is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBorder.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBorder"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="A" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Green"/>
        <TextBlock Text="B" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="Green"/>
        <TextBlock Text="C" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Green"/>
        <TextBlock Text="D" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(tried with or without the margin, with or without the alignement)

and it generate this:
[image]

doing the background like this is a bit weird, but it's just to reproduce my issue.

Any reason why I get those borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `SnapsToDevicePixels` to `True` on your main Grid.

Comment: That's working, thank you! Do you know why it's not set to true by default?

Comment: @J4N You're welcome (: . [this link may help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels)